# How to verify if a check box is checked when ::after gets added once check box is checked

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium

I'm trying to verify whether a check box is checked or not in the selenium code. It gets added ::after once the checkbox is checked but I'm not able to verify that pseudo element exist or not. Can anybody please help me to resolve that issue? I was not able to find a correct JavaScript snippet for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find the element and use isSelected.

```
isChecked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("label[class='labelContainer']/input")).isSelected();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check pseudo element properties properties. E.g.

```js
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('h1'), '::after').getPropertyValue('content'));
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      h1::after {
        content: "new";
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>site</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My code is bit different from this example. I'm getting just  ::after only. There is no either content or any tag long with ::after

Comment: What is the meaning of "::after" if it adds nothing in styles? Why simple classname not used?